# How to use the @ symbol to decorate a function in python

Tags: python, closures, decorator

Here is an easy example of what I want to do in my code:

```
def deco(func):
    def inner(x):
        num = func.__closure__[0].cell_contents
        print("I multiply with " + str(num))
        return func(x)
    return inner


def make_multiplier_of(n):
    def multiply(x):
        return x*n
    return multiply


multi7 = make_multiplier_of(7)
multi7 = deco(multi7)
print(multi7(5))
```

This runs perfectly fine.

But if I change the code to:

```
@deco
def make_multiplier_of(n):
    def multiply(x):
        return x*n
    return multiply
```

I get the error:

```
num = func.__closure__[0].cell_contents
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I fix this? / Use the @ symbol to decorate my function?

Comment: A primary problem I’d say is that your decorator expects to know too many internal details of what it’s decorating. It probably shouldn’t be playing around with implementation details such as `__closure__` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use the decorator the `func` params is `make_multiplier_of` and not `multiply` thats why `func.__closure__[0].cell_contents` throw ans exception.

Here is the fix if you are able to change the decorator.

```
def deco(func):
    def inner(x):
        print("I multiply with " + str(x))
        return func(x)
    return inner

@deco
def make_multiplier_of(n):
    def multiply(x):
        return x*n
    return multiply


multi7 = make_multiplier_of(7)
print(multi7(5))
```

Be carefull the behaviour of the use as `multi7 = deco(multi7)` will change.

Best regards

Comment: I found it useful to remember that `@deco` actually do `make_multiplier_of = deco(make_multiplier_of)`